# Find out a posts taxonomy

Tags: wordpress

I have a posts page (using single.php )and I want to be able to some how query the post for which taxonomy category it's in. Is this possible? I've looked at every wp function under the sun and none seem to enable you to query for this.

I have used this on other types of pages:

```
 if(is_tax('taxnamehere')) {
```

But when I get in to single.php (the post page) this no longer works

Answer (score 0):

Found it.

```
$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID , 'leadership' );
if(is_array($terms)) {
    foreach( $terms as $term ) {
        $tax = $term->slug;
    unset($term);
    }
}
```

returns the category within the taxonomy.